# Magento2 How to get current compare product collection on product list and product detail page?

Tags: magento2, collection, product-list, compare, view

I am using `Magento2.3.1` and I need to list and detail page current product if add compare product than getting list and count on list and detail page. So I try to detail and list page checkbox with compare link click than product add and remove on one link.

If anyone this type of functionality working code share with and appreciated for help.

i share with u screen this type showing
[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**In your block class**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\CustomerData\CompareProducts $compareProducts
) {
    $this->compareProducts = $compareProducts;
}

public function getComparedProductsList(){
    return $this->compareProducts->getSectionData();
}
```

**Add below code in your phtml file**

```
<?php
    $compareCollection = $block->getComparedProductsList();
 ?>
<div class="compared-producr-items">
<?php foreach($compareCollection['items'] as $comparelist){                        
 ?>
    <div class="compared-list">
        <a class="remove-item" data-href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() ?>ajaxcompare/compare/remove/" data-compare="<?php echo $comparelist['id']; ?>">x</a>
        <span class="compare-item-name"><?php echo $comparelist['name']; ?></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: not working on it this code.my requirement check it please

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: my requiremnt is on list and detail page checbox icon with comapre link show and if unchecked compare link to remove it if laready compare on list.

Comment: if u have to customize and any other plugin please share me.

Comment: @RvSingh : Have you found any solution? I am also facing the same.

Comment: @KishorThummar : I have used your code but that is not working on catalog, cms & product page for me in case of guest user. but for compare page , cart page and checkout page it's working. Please help me.